# How do I Find a string in a file and place a string above it?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, script

I would like to find the String `__MARKER__` in `someFile.txt` and place a String above it (e.g. `Hello World!`).

How would I do that using `sed`?

```
sed -i -e 's/__MARKER__/Hello world\n__MARKER__/' someFile.txt
```

However, after running the above snippet, the contents of `someFile.txt` is below:

```
Hello worldn__MARKER__
```

Contents of `someFile.txt` before manipulation:

```
__MARKER__
```

Contents of `someFile.txt` after manipulation:

```
Hello World!
__MARKER__
```

Comment: Also asked here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1044271/10127 -- did the answers there not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s/…/…/` is a substitution, replacing the first `…` with the second `…`. You can use a new line in your string to insert text above or below a line break.

```sh
sed -i -e 's/__MARKER__/Hello world\
__MARKER__/' someFile.txt
```

Escape the new line with a backslash, else you'll get "unescaped newline inside substitute pattern". To type a new line in Terminal, use ⌥↩︎.

You can use `&` as shorthand for the match, so you don't need to retype it in the replacement.

```sh
sed -i -e 's/__MARKER__/Hello world\
&/' someFile.txt
```

Comment: What if `someFile.txt` has `// __MARKER__` in it? Notice the `//`. Do I have to escape it?

Comment: @Nicholas Then you'll get `// Hello world` followed by `__MARKER__` on the line after. I'm not sure what you're referring to with escaping `//`, the substitution purely looks for the marker string and replaces it with the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, is `sed`'s *insert* function.

**input:**

```
cat someFile.txt
```

**output:**

```
apple
orange
grape
pineapple
plum
_MARKER_
banana
```

---

**input:**

```
sed '/_MARKER_/i\
Hello World!
' someFile.txt
```

**output:**

```
apple
orange
grape
pineapple
plum
Hello World!
_MARKER_
banana
```